# Decrypting the column level SQL encrypted values using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, cryptography, simplemembership

I have been started reading and experimenting the encryption and decryption techniques in C#

I have tried Data Encryption and Decryption in SQL Server 2008 using the information available in the following link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-sql-server-2008/

By using following query (from example of link) I can able to decrypt a value using SQL queries

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_password
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Cert_Password WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!2';
SELECT CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY([Password]) as varchar(200))
FROM Security
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY Sym_password;
```

How can I do the same operation from my C# application?

In my MVC application, I'm using email address as my username to login (password is hashed by default using simple membership). Please suggest me the best ways to encrypt the email field in SQL level and decrypt those values in C#(application level)

When a user enters his username (email) in application, How can I encrypt that value in application side and compare it with the encrypted value in the SQL records.

Comment: Mainstream support for SQL Server 2008 ended 2 years ago. Consider moving to column level encryption in SQL Server 2016 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine). That allows encryption to be done by the SQL Server client API instead of the server transparently to your code.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman for the information. But unfortunately I have only 2008 edition right now.

Comment: Does it need to be an encrypted email? Why not use a salted hash?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    UserID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    [Login] varchar(32) unique,
    [Email] varchar(32) unique,
    [Password] varbinary(256) not null,
    [BackupCode] varbinary(256) not null,
    ModifiedDate datetime default (getdate()));

DECLARE @EncryptionKey nvarchar(32) = '007London' ;
DECLARE @Password varchar(32) = 'LoveDanger&Romance' ;
DECLARE @Code varchar(32) = 'GoNawazGo' ;
```

Insert Query(encryption):

```
INSERT [Users] ([Login], [Email], [Password], [BackupCode])
SELECT 'JamesBond', 'test@test.com',
    EncryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, @Password),
    EncryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, @Code),
```

Select Query(decryption):

```
 SELECT *, 
     DecryptedPassword = Convert(varchar(32),
     DecryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, [Password])),
     [Password],
     DecryptedCode = Convert(varchar(32),
     DecryptByPassPhrase(@EncryptionKey, [BackupCode])),
     [BackupCode],
     FROM [Users]
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Query(decryption):

Convert(varchar(32) should be Convert(**n**varchar(32)

In nvarchar the code points for standard ASCII letters are the same as for ASCII but padded out with a 0x00 byte.